# why is CSS Float property overlapping below content?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I'm having issues with how my CSS float property aligns. In the "About Me" section, I want the `<p>` elements to be on the right side of the image however, the text and information in my "Portfolio" section are also floating around the image. How do I format it so that the text in the "About Me" section is the only text wrapping around the image, and the "portfolio" banner/header is on its own line and functioning like a block element?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>About</title>
<style>
    #aboutImage, #headerImage{
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #about, #portfolio{
        background-color: #ff80d5;
        font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 100;
        block-size: 50px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 2%;
        
    }

    #portraits, #stationary{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Gills Sans, sans-serif;
        color: #ff80d5;
        font-weight: 200;
    }
    p{
        font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #ff80d5;
        border-style: dotted;
        text-indent: 15px;
    }
    #menu, ul li{
        text-align: center;
        display: inline;
        font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 3%;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ff80d5; 
    }
    #caption{
        color: #ff80d5;
        font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    #portfolioImg{
        width: 353px;
        height: 447px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #portraitGrid, #stationaryGrid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        justify-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        grid-row-gap: 25px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    #aboutImage{
        float: left;
    }
    #portfolioBlock{
        display:block;
    }
        

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <img ID ="headerImage" src = "Images/Origami Mami Logo.jpeg">
    <div ID = "menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href = "">Portfolio </a></li>

        <li> <a href = "">Video</a></li>

        <li><a href = "">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div ID="aboutMe">
    <h1 ID = "about">About Me</h1>

    <br>

    <img ID = "aboutImage" class= "alignLeft" src = "Images/Ms. Mami.jpeg">

    <p class="aboutText"> A Brooklyn native, Origami Mami (Kevin) has been folding for over 15 years. After a friend taught him how to fold an origami flower pot, 
        Origami Mami has been folding almost non-stop since. After a family member was diagnosed with Breast Cancer, and later another with AIDS, 
        he folded and gifted anything he made. The joyful and positive reactions from his sick loved ones gave him the greatest feeling, and which 
        led him to contiuosly fold.
    </p>
    
    <p>Originally teaching himself how to fold anything he found instructions to on the internet, he began adding greater color to his work by 
        making portraits and stationary cards. Now you can spread the same love and joy Origami Mami gave to his loved ones to yours. All portaits 
    and cards are created with careful attention to color, shapes, and patterns.
    </p>
    </div>

    <div ID = "portfolioBlock">

    <h1 ID = "portfolio">Portfolio</h1>
    <p>Each piece of work is carefully thought out in regards to color, paint, origami design, and overall works. Some designs are simple, while
        others a bit more abstract. The statement and takeaway message in each of these pieces is simply, love! With both portraits and stationary
        each piece can easily be gifted, and portraits can be used as decor for home, and/or offices, which helps upkeep the spread of joy. 
    </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: by elements, I mean the P tags/paragraphs. Sorry if my diction is not correct or accurate, I'm new at this/teaching myself, so still wrapping my head around the lingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `#aboutMe` (or any other similar element) to make the subsequent elements start *below* it even when it contains floated elements.

```css
#aboutImage,
#headerImage {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#about,
#portfolio {
  background-color: #ff80d5;
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  block-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

#portraits,
#stationary {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gills Sans, sans-serif;
  color: #ff80d5;
  font-weight: 200;
}

p {
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ff80d5;
  border-style: dotted;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

#menu,
ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 3%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff80d5;
}

#caption {
  color: #ff80d5;
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

#portfolioImg {
  width: 353px;
  height: 447px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#portraitGrid,
#stationaryGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#aboutImage {
  float: left;
}

#portfolioBlock {
  display: block;
}
#aboutMe {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<img ID="headerImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300">
<div ID="menu">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="">Portfolio </a></li>

    <li> <a href="">Video</a></li>

    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div ID="aboutMe">
  <h1 ID="about">About Me</h1>

  <br>

  <img ID="aboutImage" class="alignLeft" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600" />">

  <p class="aboutText"> A Brooklyn native, Origami Mami (Kevin) has been folding for over 15 years. After a friend taught him how to fold an origami flower pot, Origami Mami has been folding almost non-stop since. After a family member was diagnosed with Breast Cancer, and
    later another with AIDS, he folded and gifted anything he made. The joyful and positive reactions from his sick loved ones gave him the greatest feeling, and which led him to contiuosly fold.
  </p>

  <p>Originally teaching himself how to fold anything he found instructions to on the internet, he began adding greater color to his work by making portraits and stationary cards. Now you can spread the same love and joy Origami Mami gave to his loved ones
    to yours. All portaits and cards are created with careful attention to color, shapes, and patterns.
  </p>
</div>

<div ID="portfolioBlock">

  <h1 ID="portfolio">Portfolio</h1>
  <p>Each piece of work is carefully thought out in regards to color, paint, origami design, and overall works. Some designs are simple, while others a bit more abstract. The statement and takeaway message in each of these pieces is simply, love! With both
    portraits and stationary each piece can easily be gifted, and portraits can be used as decor for home, and/or offices, which helps upkeep the spread of joy.
  </p>
</div>
```